# How has Arduino been used in the classroom?

Tags: project

I remember seeing [Primo](http://techcrunch.com/2013/11/24/primo/), this robot that is based on Arduino and serves to teach kids to program. My interest in the platform comes from there, but it is always nice to learn about other cool applications.

What other applications are there that utilise Arduino for K-12 education?

Comment: This is very broad. What age range? What type of education?

Comment: Edited to mean only k-12. Is that still too broad?

Comment: There's linkbot http://www.barobo.com/

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Sparki](http://arcbotics.com/products/sparki/start) from Arcbotics as a robotics platform. It's uses Arduino Sketch to program and a modified Arduino IDE.

Sensors for line following , edge detection, distance and light level sensing are built in. Also the creators are focused on education so the material and projects are teaching oriented.

The Community seems pretty active and engaged too so the material should build over time.

Answer (score 1):

We have been using Arduino's to teach basic microcontroller concepts in classes focused on environmental monitoring & instrumentation, rather than just electronics:

[An Arduino UNO based Datalogger for the Classroom](http://edwardmallon.wordpress.com/2015/12/22/arduino-uno-based-data-logger-with-no-soldering/)

The IDE abstracts away enough of the low level details that you can get students into programming quickly, while still exposing them to enough of hardware side of things. I am not sure what other platform would let us take true beginners so far, so quickly.